# Symmetric spaces and spherical functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group, $\sigma$ an involutive automorphism and $K$ a subgroup such that $(G^\sigma)_0\subset K\subset G^\sigma$. Then $M=G/K$ is a Riemannian symmetric space.

Conversely, if $M$ is a symmetric space, for $x\in M$, let $S_x$ be the symmetry at $x$, then define $G(M)$ the subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$  generated by the $S_xS_y$, $x,y\in M$. Fix a base point $o\in M$ and $K(M)=\operatorname{Stab}(o)$ for the action of $G(M)$ on $M$, then $M$ is isomorphic as a symmetric space to $G(M)/K(M)$.

Thus, there is a canonical pair associated to $M$. Also, $(G,K)$ and $(G(M),K(M))$ are both Gelfand pairs. My question is, are the spherical functions for these two pairs related ? (and thus, maybe only depending on the symmetric space $M$ in a way).

I know that if we define $G_\sigma=\{x\sigma(x)^{-1}\vert x\in G\}$, and $\tau:G\to \operatorname{Aut}(M)$ by $\tau(g):xK\mapsto gxK$, then $G(M)$ is the subgroup of $\tau(G)$ generated by $\tau(G_\sigma)$. Furthermore, $\tau(G)\simeq G/\cap_g gKg^{-1}$. Given an irreducible representation $\pi$ of $G$ which has a unit $K$-invariant vector $\xi$, then $\bigcap_g gKg^{-1}\subset \ker \pi$, so $\pi$ induces an irreducible representation of $\tau(G)$ which restricts to $G(M)$.

But this representation may not be irreducible, so we cannot say that the spherical function of $(G,K)$ associated to $\pi$ is also a spherical function of $(G(M),K(M))$.